# Dump Contents of RDS Postgres Query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-dump

Short Version of this Question:

I'd like to dump the contents of a Postgres query from a db instance hosted in RDS inside of a shell script.

Complete Version:

Right now I'm writing a shell script that I would like to dump the contents of a query into a .dump file from a source database, and run the dump file on a destination database instance. Both db instances are hosted in RDS.

MySQL allows you to do this using the [mysqldump tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where), but the recommended answer to this problem in Postgres seems to be to use the [COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). However, the [COPY command isn't available in RDS instances](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141798). The recommended solution in this case seems to be to use the '\copy' command, which does the same thing locally using the psql tool. However, [it doesn't seem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192276/using-copy-in-psql-script-does-not-write-to-file) like this is a support option inside of a shell script.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `\copy` from inside `psql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with shell, but I have used batch file in Windows to dump output of query to a file and to import the file on another instance.

Here is what I used to export from postgres RDS to file on Windows.

```
SET PGPASSWORD=your_password
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime"
psql -h your_host -U your_username -d your_databasename -c "\copy (your_query) TO 
path\file_name.sql"
```

All above commands are in one batch file.